# How to initialize marquee on mobile and destroy on desktop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i initialize marquee on mobile and destroy it on desktop with jQuery ? each time i minimize the window width, i want to check if it hits the minimum threshold and just say if its less than < 767px, i want the marquee to initialize. If user expand the window width > 767px, i want the marquee to be destroy..

The code i have now seems to be buggy as it crashes the whole site..

The is the repo i'm using for reference https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.marquee@1.6.0/jquery.marquee.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    if (window.jQuery) {
      $(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width <= 767) {
          $('.tt-services-listing').marquee({
            duration: 20000,
            duplicated: true,
            delayBeforeStart: 0,
            startVisible: true,
          });
        }
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
          if (width >= 768) {
            // I want to check here each time the user resize, if hits the threshold, DESTROY marquee here
            $('.tt-services-listing').marquee('destroy');
          } else {
            $('.tt-services-listing').marquee({
              duration: 20000,
              duplicated: true,
              delayBeforeStart: 0,
              startVisible: true,
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: PS, the `$(function () {` (*DOM ready*) is unnecessary inside a `window.onload`. Also, the `window.onload` is bad practice since it can cause flash of content when its JS contents initialize. I would just stick to simply placing my `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag, or use the `defer` attribute if there's no other way but to keep it in `<head>`.

Comment: If you read your own code carefully, *"whenever window resizes, constantly destroy the marquee whilst width >= 768"* - and the opposite... You should use an `if` statement to check whether your plugin is initialized or not - and act accordingly: *"if marquee is not initialized AND width < 768 = initialize it"* and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check whether the plugin was initialized on that element or not.
You can assign a `data-*` attribute like `data-marqueeinit`.
Also you could use `window.matchMedia()` to check for the current root width

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  // Marquee

  const m768 = matchMedia("(width < 768px)");
  const $listings = $('.tt-services-listing');
  const marqueeOptions = {duration: 20000, duplicated: true, delayBeforeStart: 0, startVisible: true};

  const handleMarquee = () => {
    if (m768.matches && !$listings.data("marqueeinit")) {
      $listings.data("marqueeinit", 1);
      $listings.marquee(marqueeOptions);
    }
    else if (!m768.matches && $listings.data("marqueeinit")) {
      $listings.removeData("marqueeinit");
      $listings.marquee("destroy");
    }
  };

  $(window).on("resize", handleMarquee);
  handleMarquee();

});
```

```html
<div class="tt-services-listing">Resize the window. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Aliquid.</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.marquee@1.6.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

is it compulsary to use jQuery?
if not then i believe it can achieve it by media query also....

just add these lines to your css file...

//css starts here //

```
marquee {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    marquee {
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you assure the interval is still not running in the background?